# Find expected number of events happening given that events are dependent

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence

So, my question frames like this:

There are n houses in row and there is a street light in between the houses. So, n-1 street lights.
The glowing of street light depends on both the immediate houses on the right and left to consume power from it.

Let's say probability that a house gives power to the street light is 'p'. Also, if a house gives power to street light on the left then it will give power to street light on the right also.

First question is:

If the event of a street light glowing is Ai, then are these events independent?,  which can be shown that they are not independent.

My main question is:
**What is expected number of street lights that be on ?**

Given these events are dependent, I can not use any distribution formula as such.

Comment: Expectation of a sum is the sum of expectations - that doesn't rely on independence.

Comment: @Glen_b, sorry but can you elaborate more ? I can give probabilities of let's say m street lights on. But how to calculate expected number of street lights to be on ?

Comment: Compute the expectation of the indicator that a light is on.  (The indicator equals $1$ when the light is on, $0$ when it is off.)

Comment: @whuber, Ok, but in that case, won't the probabilities will redundantly used ? For example, for the first two street lights be on, the probability of the second house will be taken twice. Is that correct ?

Comment: Reconsider the first comment by @Glen_b.